# get the ParseFile from the ParseQuery

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am writing an address book APP and using the Parse service.
I also use the listview and BaseAdapter to implement the APP
There are many people I saved as the ParseObject.
And each ParseObject includes a photo saved as file.
I get all ParseObjects by :

```
ArrayList<ParseObject> list = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("member");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
       list = (ArrayList<ParseObject>) objects;
       mMyadapter = new MyAdapter(context, list);
    }
    else {
    }
 });
```

in the adapter, I want to show the image from the ParseFile
My question is :
How do I get the ParseFile from the list?
I tried below code but the APP will shut down suddenly.
I wrote the getView method in the MyAdapter like below:

```
 ParseFile pf = (ParseFile) list.get(position).get("photo1");
 pf.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
           Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
           viewTag.imageView1.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
        else {
            Log.d("debug", "bad");
        }
    }
 });
```

I can not use the getUrl() neither....
Can someone tell me how to modify it? Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to initialize `list`.
2. How are you setting the adapter of your ViewGroup? At the moment, you're creating a new adapter only when your ParseQuery is done. Your adapter may not be set properly.
3. Since `list` could point to `new ArrayList<ParseObject>()` or `(ArrayList<ParseObject>) objects` depending on whether ParseQuery is done, it's possible that you're calling `list.get()` on an invalid position.

In short, make your member variables local. Also, if `MyAdapter` is an anonymous class, pull that code out into a static inner class so it doesn't refer to its containing class' member variables. Use `getItem()` to access your ParseObjects, not `list.get()`.

Comment: as the above code, I set the adapter when the "done" event happens.
and after this event the view will be shown.
Could you tell me what's the difference of `getItem()` and `list.get()`?

Comment: Have you called `setAdapter()` anywhere?

Comment: `getItem()` gets an item from the list stored internally in the adapter - this is the same list that you passed into `super()`. `list.get()` is bad, because `list` doesn't necessarily refer to the same data. It could even refer to your empty list.

Comment: Yes, I called 'setAdapter()' within the `findInBackground()` after the MyAdapter constructor. the getItem function is just `return list.get(position)`...Did I do sth wrong?
btw, I found the problem is the ParseFile I got is null...I am finding the root cause.